# how to find out three consecutive positive integers in an array

Tags: c#, linq

i have a list of differences between gain vs loss for every year, some of them are positive and some are negative, now i want to check if there any 3 consecutive years who has positive value as a difference. and if there are any 3 years then i need to select the lowest number out of them.

So in the example given below year 2022 2023 and 2024 has positive int value, among which 59 is the lowest one, so that should be the answer

e.g.

```
Year         2021   2022   2023  2024   2025   2026
differences   -20    240    59   120    -34     23
```

Comment: In your given example what will be the expected output

Comment: question edited and updated

Comment: This did not answer my question, Can you show us your effort to solve this problem. What challenge you faced while solving this problem. For me it looks like homework/interview question

Comment: @AjaySutar Show us the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Yeah, you post a specification, not a question. Where are you stuck? Also, what kind of structure stores your data? I.e. what exactly is the source of the LINQ statement?

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] differences = new int[] { -20, 240, 59, 120, -34, 23 };
var minScores = Enumerable.Range(0, differences.Length - 2)
     .Where(index => differences[index] >= 0 && differences[index + 1] >= 0 && differences[index + 2] >= 0)
     .Select(index => new int[] { differences[index], differences[index + 1], differences[index + 2] })
     .Select(t => t.Min());
```

The above code first finds the indexes which are positive and their two next elements are also positive. Then it will select an array with three elements containing the positive numbers. At last, we will select the lowest number.
Result:

> 59

If you want to select the related three years too, you could do something like:

```
int[] years = new int[] { 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026 };
int[] differences = new int[] { -20, 240, 59, 120, -34, 23 };

var consecutiveIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, differences.Length - 2)
    .Where(index => differences[index] >= 0 && differences[index + 1] >= 0 && differences[index + 2] >= 0);

var reports = consecutiveIndexes.Select(index =>
    "The score "
    + (new int[] { differences[index], differences[index + 1], differences[index + 2] }).Min()
    + $" is the lowest in these years: {years[index]}, {years[index + 1]}, {years[index + 2]}");
```

Result:

> "The score 59 is the lowest in these years: 2022, 2023, 2024"

Comment: This isn't what OP is trying to do.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar You're right, sorry. I answered before the update. Answer updated.

Comment: I still think this is different. OP has a list of objects with two properties: Year, and Differences. Where there are three sequential years (e.g. 2022, 2023, 2024) whose values for Differences are all positive, OP wants to find the lowest Differences value and corresponding year. With the emphasis OP put on sequential years, it suggests to me that years aren't always sequential (perhaps 2010, 2012, 2013, 2014, etc.)

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Well, I thought given the idea of how to select in the scores, OP would be able to solve their problem. But still, you're right there might be some intentions with those exceptions, I'll wait for OP to enlighten us with these details. The answer is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just *loop*?

```
// let answer be -1, when we don't have three positive consequent numbers 
int result = -1;

for (int i = 0, count = 0; i < differences.Length; ++i) 
  if (differences[i] > 0) {
    if (++count >= 3) {
      int min = 
        Math.Min(Math.Min(differences[i - 2], differences[i - 1]), differences[i]);

      result = result < 0 ? min : Math.Min(result, min);
    }
  }
  else
    count = 0;
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tvsRF8)

Comment: You can combine `if (differences[i] > 0 && (++count) >= 3) {...`

Answer (score 0):

With [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) it's as easy as:

```cs
var values = new (int year, int value)[] {
    (2021, -20), (2022, 240), (2023, 59), (2024, 120), (2025, -34), (2026, 23)
};

var minima = values
    .Window(3)
    .Where(w => w.All(x => x.value > 0))
    .Select(w => w.Min(x => x.value))
```